# Why isn't a Task automatically cancelled when a View disappears?

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await, task

According to Apple's documentation, a task{} will automatically cancel when a view disappears.

> SwiftUI will automatically cancel the task at some point after the
> view disappears before the action completes.

Why, in this scenario, is the Task in the 'loadData' method not cancelled when the ChildView disappears? (When navigating back to the 'ParentView')

```
struct ChildView: View {
    
    @State private var data: [Double] = []
    
    private func loadData() async {
        // Why isn't this Task automatically cancelled when the ChildView disappears?
        // The Task is still executing in the background.
        Task(priority: .background) {
            // Simulating heavy data processing.
            self.data = (1...3_000_000).map { _ in Double.random(in: -10...30) }
            print("Task ended")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is a child view")
            .task { await loadData() }
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: { ChildView() }) {
                Text("Show child view")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The task in 'loadData' continues executing even when the ChildView disappears. It also executes multiple times when the ChildView is initialized multiple times in a row.

This could potentially lead to memory leaks, especially when using a class with a @Published 'data' property instead of the @State property in the ChildView. What is the correct implementation for using a Task() in such a scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SwiftUI does cancel the task created implicitly by the `task` view modifier, but that task doesn't do the "heavy data processing". That task only creates a subtask to run `loadData`. This subtask completes almost immediately.

This is because all `loadData` does is it creates a *top level task* by using `Task { ... }` and does nothing else. By the time your view disappears, the `loadData` task would have already completed. The top level task, however, does all the "heavy data processing", and because it is a top-level task (i.e. not a child of the `loadData` task), it doesn't get cancelled when `loadData` is cancelled.

You should not create a top level task here. Put the heavy data processing directly in `loadData`.

Also, task cancellation is cooperative - `loadData` should also check `Task.isCancelled` and stop what it's doing.

```
private func loadData() async {
    for _ in 1...3_000_000 {
        if Task.isCancelled { // for example
            break
        }
        self.data.append(Double.random(in: -10..<30))
    }
    print("Task ended")
}
```

Comment: As you mentioned above, the execution of the '.task{}' modifier, as well as 'loadData', completes immediately after creating a top-level 'Task()'. The issue arose from using an unstructured top-level 'Task' in 'loadData' without any cancellation policy. Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Sweeper nailed it on the head. (+1)

A few additional observations/clarifications:

1. The first problem is that `Task {…}` is [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency). In structured concurrency, you can “let Swift handle some behaviors like propagating cancellation for you”, but in unstructured concurrency, you bear this responsibility yourself. For example, you would have to employ `withTaskCancellationHandler`:

   ```swift
   private func loadData() async throws {
       let task = Task(priority: .background) { [iterations] in
           try (1...iterations).map { index in
               try Task.checkCancellation()
               return Double.random(in: -10...30)
           }
       }

       data = try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
           try await task.value
       } onCancel: {
           task.cancel()
       }
   }
   ```
2. The second issue is that a computationally intensive routine must check to see if the task was canceled. I generally prefer `try Task.checkCancellation()`, as shown in my example above, which not only checks for cancelation, but also throws a `CancellationError` if canceled. (This way, the caller also knows it was canceled and can act accordingly.) But you can also use a manual test for `if Task.isCancelled {…}`, as shown by Sweeper.

   Obviously, if you’re going to throw the `CancellationError` with `checkCancellation` (as shown in the examples above), the caller would presumably catch it:

   ```swift
   var body: some View {
       Text("This is a child view")
           .task {
               do {
                   print("starting")
                   try await loadData()
                   print("finished")
               } catch {
                   print("caught error", error)
               }
           }
   }
   ```
3. Obviously, in point 1, above, you can see that unstructured concurrency complicates our code a little. But if all you want is to get this off the main actor, but remain within structured concurrency, you can use a non-isolated `async` function (which `loadData` already is).

   Thanks to [SE-0338 - Clarify the Execution of Non-Actor-Isolated Async Functions](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md), a non-isolated `async` function already runs off the current actor. So you get this off the main actor, but by remaining within structured concurrency, it significantly simplifies our code:

   ```swift
   private func loadData() async throws {
       data = try (1...iterations).map { _ in
           try Task.checkCancellation()
           return Double.random(in: -10...30)
       }
   }
   ```

   Obviously, if you prefer to use unstructured concurrency (e.g., to specify the priority), then feel free. But make sure you understand what you are signing up for (e.g., manually handling of cancelation).

---

As an aside, you should avoid blocking the Swift concurrency task with a computationally intensive routine. You can resolve this by periodically calling `Task.yield()`:

```swift
private func loadData() async throws {
    var array: [Double] = []
    array.reserveCapacity(iterations)

    for index in 1 ... iterations {
        if index.isMultiple(of: 1_000) {
            await Task.yield()
            try Task.checkCancellation()
        }
        array.append(.random(in: -10...30))
    }

    data = array
}
```

Now, this pattern of periodically yielding is generally only a concern when writing long-running, computationally intensive routines. If you simply `await` some other `async` function, then this is not necessary. It is only a concern for long-running or otherwise blocking functions.

See [Integrate a blocking function into Swift async](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72872967/1271826) or [How do I run an async function within a @MainActor class on a background thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76665311/1271826)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! It truly addresses all my questions. The third point seems to be the optimal solution for me. However, I will delve deeper into the other options to gain a better understanding of the topic. The example of a heavily computational task was used merely to illustrate that the Task in the 'loadData' method doesn't cancel when a view disappears. In a real-world scenario, the task would likely be simpler and less intensive. My goal was to find a proper solution that prevents any potential memory leaks. Once again, thank you.